# Ejecutar Ajax sólo con javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Me gustaría saber como se puede mejorar el siguiente código para hacer llamadas con ajax http reques.

```html
function fn_EjecutarAjax(s_Metodo, s_Url, s_Parametros, b_Asincrono, s_TipoRespuesta, s_FuncionEjecutar)
{
 var s_MensajeError = '';
 var ESTADO_CORRECTO = 4;
 var ESTATUS_CORRECTO = 200;
 var xmlhttp_Conexion = fn_AjaxHttpReques();
 try
 {
  if(xmlhttp_Conexion != false)
  {
   xmlhttp_Conexion.onreadystatechange  =
   function()
   {
    if(xmlhttp_Conexion.readyState === ESTADO_CORRECTO)
    {
     if(xmlhttp_Conexion.status === ESTATUS_CORRECTO)
     {
      var s_Ejecutar = s_FuncionEjecutar + '(\'' + xmlhttp_Conexion.responseText + '\');';
      s_Ejecutar = s_Ejecutar.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ' ');
      eval(s_Ejecutar);
     }
    }
   }
   switch(s_Metodo)
   {
    case 'GET':
     if(s_TipoDatosEnviar === 'JSON')
     {
      s_MensajeError = 'Los parametros no se pueden enviar en JSON para el Método GET, favor de verificar el envío de parámetros.';
      return false;
     }
     var s_UrlCompleta = s_Url + '?' + s_Parametros;
     xmlhttp_Conexion.open(s_Metodo, s_UrlCompleta, b_Asincrono);
     xmlhttp_Conexion.send(null);
    break;
    case 'POST':
     xmlhttp_Conexion.open(s_Metodo, s_Url, b_Asincrono);
     xmlhttp_Conexion.responseType = s_TipoRespuesta;
     s_TipoDatosEnviar = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
     xmlhttp_Conexion.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", s_TipoDatosEnviar);
     xmlhttp_Conexion.send(s_Parametros);
    break;
    default:
     var s_MensajeError = 'El método solicitado no es correcto, la función Ajax sólo acepta método [GET] y método [POST], favor de verificar con el desarrollador de la aplicación.';
     break;
   }
  }
 }
 catch (Error_Ajax)
 {
  console.log(Error_Ajax);
  return false;
 }
}
```

Creen que esta bien, como podría ser la mejor opción, o me faltaría algo mas que validar.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas espero esto sea lo que buscas y te ayude saludos

```js
document.getElementById("cambiar").addEventListener("click",cambiar);
 
function cambiar(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 
    xhr.open("GET","https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",true);
    xhr.send();
 
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("parrafo").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
    <pre id="parrafo">consultar usuarios!</pre>
    <button id="cambiar">Consultar</button>
    <script src="ejemplo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```